# Exception occurs when using MongoDB driver for DotNet Core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, driver, .net-core

I'm working on solution on the following stack:

- ASP.NET Core
- .NET Core
- MongoDB

...using this driver for communication with the database: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver.Core/
...version 2.4.1

I'm trying to instantiate the MongoClient like this:

```
var options = provider.GetService<IOptions<MongoDbSettings>>();
var client = new MongoClient(options.Value.ConnectionString);
```

But the last statement errors out saying:

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code

and

> Additional information: Method not found: 'Void MongoDB.Driver.ReadPreference..ctor

I've noticed that the class *MongoClient* is in the MongoDB.Driver -namespace, not in MongoDB.Driver.Core. 
Does that mean it is not compatible with .Net Core?
If so, how do I then connect to the database?

All help appreciated!

Regards,
Jon

Comment: `MongoDB.Driver.Core` namespace is unrelated to .NET Core. It's just the commonly shared classes which are used by the other MongoDb packages. I suspect you have somewhere mixed up dependencies. Do you still have references to old mongodb driver packages? 2.3 for example? Maybe in other projects which your main project references?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me Tseng!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this driver:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/

version 2.3.0, which solved the problem.